# Binding.pry after typing pry in VSCODE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

Because Atom will be deprecated quite soon I had to switch to vscode which is really nice after made some configuration setup. One thing is missing compared to my Atom setups - in Atom after I type `pry + enter` the `binding.pry` shows up. Like below:

`Atom pry`

[image]

`Atom enter`

[image]

and we've got `binding.pry`. I've no idea how it was made in Atom, is there any chance to get the same in VSCODE ?

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+P`

Comment: On Mac this just moves me to a line above

Comment: where do you type `pry`, have you looked at snippets, with Hypersnips you can define auto-snippets no need to type Enter/TAb

Comment: @rioV8 Have you read my question? screenshots are from Atom IDE, I want to have the same in vscode.

Comment: Mother of perl, like I already described - when I type, inside the Ruby file, word of `pry` and hit `enter` I should get `binding.pry` as a result.

Comment: what is this dot in front of `binding.pry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many ways and I must create a custom snippet.
To create or edit your own snippets, select `User Snippets` under `File > Preferences` (`Code > Preferences` on `macOS`), and then select the language (by [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)) for which the snippets should appear, or the `New Global Snippets` file option if they should appear for all languages.
[ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

Here is my snippet:

```
"Print to console": {
        "prefix": "pry",
        "body": [
            "binding.pry",
        ],
        "description": "Add binding for ruby code using gem pry"
    }
```